# Image uploader that can edit order of images

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, flash

I need a tutorial or code that can help me to create an image uploader that can also be used to edit the order of the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/

Comment: Thank you, you have been a great help!!